Problem of reversed flow in Fluent iteration
I'm work on simulation of non-Newtonian fluids in horizontal pipe, I'm use a condensate of gas rheo=690 , but in the operation of process of simulation we see the problem of reversed flow when the start of iteration, this problem we not see in the fluid of great density, how we solve this problem?

In turbulent flow, if the flow is from left to right, do all the molecules move left to right only? do they all move at the same velocity?
